# localhost for xampp not working

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I was working on xampp for 8 months now, without any problems, but suddenly when I got a virus, localhost was not working! I eliminated the virus via AVG anivirus but still nothing.

I unistalled xampp, and installed it back again but still nothing happened. I installed both 1.8.1 and 1.6.4 versions of xampp, but nothing special.

I searched a lot of places for the solution but couldn't find it. They said about skype's port 80 (did it), about installing old version (did it), about "I corrected the path to PHP in the apache .conf file" (didn't try it because I couldn't find the path), about tring 127.0.0.1 instead (did it).

Have anyone came up to something similar?

In order to eliminate the virus I had to delete some files in regedit, I don't know if this is the problem..

Comment: yes of course it starts, it is on services also!

Answer (score 0):

Delete Reg detail will cause problem some times.
Do your data backup and re install clean windows, I think this will save time,rather then search for the web.

Comment: I just removed these ones: http://blog.teesupport.com/remove-luhe-sirefef-a-virus-tips-how-to-get-rid-of-luhe-sirefef-a-permanently/